# How to plot a line chart with multiple "Y" axis variables of different units?

Tags: charts

I have a dataset with multiple variables all correlated to time.  I am interested in plotting these variables on Y axis and time on the X axis. I have seen so many posts that talk about using secondary axis in Excel.  But I have about a dozen. I tried creating the chart in plot.ly.  You can see it [here](https://plot.ly/~shparekh/15/market-trend-vs-time/).  But it looks like I cannot update it dynamically.

Comment: What software are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Use the panel chart/small multiples concept to display your info (for examples, see this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/602084/multiple-y-axis-labels-in-excel-2010-line-chart/602117#602117), this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/757980/graph-in-excel-to-represent-correlation-of-3-parameters/757985#757985), or this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/759645/how-to-create-a-4-variables-chart-in-excel/759697#759697)).  In short, you can:

1. Create a chart with your first data series and format as desired.
2. Copy the first chart and paste as many as you have data series (about a dozen).
3. Change each chart's data series to one of your desired variables, while leaving the horizontal axis intact.
4. Arrange your charts on a single (or multiple) pages, using Excel's page layout view.

Alternatively, you could use sparklines to present an overview of your info, then provide a single chart (or two), to provide a detailed view.